# Elasticsearch query and Kibana not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to learn Elasticsearch and I am using Kibana to visualise things. I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with my mapping and queries though.

I am trying to store photo metadata (iptc data). And I have the following mapping for it:

```
  {
"settings": {
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {},
      "analyzer": {
        "keyword_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "trim"
          ],
          "char_filter": [],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        },
        "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
        },
        "edge_ngram_search_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 5,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"mappings": {
  "doc": {
    "properties": {
      "photo_added": {
        "type": "date",
        "index": true,
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd' 'H:m:s"
      },
      "photo_id": {
        "type": "long",
        "index": true
      },
      "photo_owner": {
        "type": "long",
        "index": true
      },
      "project": {
        "type": "long",
        "index": true
      },
      "iptc": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "caption/abstract": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": true
          },
          "copyright notice": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": true
          },
          "keywords": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": true,
            "fields": {
              "keywordstring": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
              },
              "edgengram": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
              },
              "completion": {
                "type": "completion"
              },
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "object name": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": true
          },
          "province/state": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": true
          },
          "sub-location": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": true
          },
          "time created": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": true
          },
          "urgency": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": true
          },
          "writer/editor": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

The thing is: I want a query that searching through the keywords and caption for the existence of the search-text. Whenever the search-text is found within keywords, the score is boosted because that indicated that the photo is of higher relevance. So I formulated the following query (where value is the search-text):

```
GET /photos/_search
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "iptc.keywords": {
              "value": "value",
              "fuzziness": 1,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "iptc.caption/abstract": {
              "value": "value",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However it does not seem to find any matches despite the fact that the value is in the documents... And I cannot seem to construct a simple match query that will match against the exact text... for example:

```
GET /photos/doc/_search?error_trace=true
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "iptc.caption/abstract": "exact value from one of the documents"
    }
  }
}
```

Will return 0 results... the search-text is however exactly in the document.. I don't know what to do know. To make matters worse (for me, since I am near bald thanks due to the frustration that is causing me) Kibana seems to act up.. I am almost sure it is something really simple (the document date is within 5 years) but when filtering for the exact copy pasted value it returns 0 results... as shown in the screenshot...

[image: Results]

I am going crazy here. Does someone know how to fix this or what in earths name I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please check with your management console window what is wrong with the mapping in there for that specific Index or try refreshing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which is in the documentation of Elastic.

> Because nested documents are indexed as separate documents, they can only be accessed within the scope of the nested query, the nested/reverse_nested aggregations, or nested inner hits.

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

So I constructed the following query which works.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "iptc",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "dis_max": {
                "queries": [
                  {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "iptc.keywords": {
                        "value": "Feyenoord",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "iptc.caption/abstract": {
                        "value": "Feyenoord",
                        "fuzziness": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```